# What can I do with private 128 bit AES Keys?

Tags: encryption, aes, forensics, rsa, truecrypt

For my studies, I am required to do an investigation on a fictional criminal VMWare image. The image is suspected of participating in DDoS attacks and other illegal activities. On this PC TrueCrypt is installed. Along with TrueCrypt, The image has Mozilla Thunderbird installed with a OpenPGP security module.

I made a raw memory.dmp of the RAM memory in the image to perform analysis.
Using [aeskeyfind](https://citp.princeton.edu/research/memory/code/) I got several results.

> michael@cf15:~/Documents/Volatility$ aeskeyfind memory.dmp
>   b4ce75c857163e668818d0d76c46bad2
>   ccf865429e42144a9dce839b036c3f7c
>   51c35f7f0b79e7d1e6d5345d2a291ac8
>   Keyfind progress: 100%

This command shows me that there are 3 AES keys present in the RAM. Using -v (verbose mode) I can see that they're all 128bits.

What exactly can someone undertake when they found these private keys unencrypted on the disk? As the OpenPGP asks for a 2048 RSA-key, I think the keys are connected to hidden TrueCrypt volumes.

Can a attacker use these keys to gain access to volumes without having the appropriate passphrase?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to decrypt things using these keys :)

First of all I would try to decrypt the hard disk (TrueCrypt) using the keys.

Regarding OpenPGP you should know that the 2048-bit RSA key is only used to decrypt a symmetric key, which can be used to decrypt the message. It's a matter of performance. You you can try decrypting the message with one of the above keys.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking *how* to use the key to decrypt the Truecrypt volume with the key.

[This](http://volatility-labs.blogspot.de/2014/01/truecrypt-master-key-extraction-and.html) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however they won't let the source code go on identifying the TrueCrypt volumes.